# In Firefox svg mask doesn't scale

Tags: css, svg, scale, mask

Using an svg to mask an image but it doesn't seem to scale right in firefox. Seems fine in safari and chrome and have suitable fallbacks for ie.

Site. http://feelfilmsdev.jynk.net

SVG
http://feelfilmsdev.jynk.net/wp-content/themes/feel-roots-theme/assets/img/feelfilms-logo.svg

CSS

```
-webkit-mask: url("../img/feelfilms-logo.svg#logo_mask");
mask: url("../img/feelfilms-logo.svg#logo_mask");
-webkit-mask-image: url(../img/feelfilms-logo.svg) top left / cover;
background-color: #d01d38;
background-blend-mode: multiply;
background-position: 50% 50%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

how it should look...

[image: how it should look]

Any ideas how i can get it to work correctly?

SVG in pastebin here. http://pastebin.com/Va5Kb8dU

Comment: I see the viewbox to preserve the size, but I don't see a height/width on either the SVG or in the CSS loading it ...

Comment: Convert the mask to maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" and convert it's contents to the new unit system.

Comment: i thought background-size: cover would cover that in the CSS. But where would it be placed in the SVG, ie which tags. There are some x,y,w,h in the viewport but maybe it needs more.

Comment: @RobertLongson - could you show that in a pastebin example? Original svg pastebin link above.

Comment: Give the mask an attribute of maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" then fix the attributes of the mask contents to be in the range 0..1 which is the range of objectBoundingBox. No, I'm not going to do all that for you.

Comment: @RobertLongson. maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" stops it working altogether and i was just asking for some clarification on your 'new unit system' and where & what these attributes are.

Comment: The new units are in the range 0 to 1 your old units are in the range 0 to 1142 in the x direction and 0 to 271 in the y direction. Divide as appropriate so all d attribute values of the path are in the new unit system.

Answer (score 3):

Use this calculator to calculate all your points to the ratio versions: http://prollygeek.com/svg/calc.html

After this your svg paths should look like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 246.059 217.445" enable-background="new 0 0 246.059 217.445" xml:space="preserve">

    <defs>
        <mask id="logo_mask2" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">

            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M0.4998801100549055,0.8250053848873644c-0.21133142864109827,0-0.38608626386354494-0.1706907692870409-0.38608626386354494-0.38608626386354494h-0.016256263741622944c0,0.2235236264473155,0.1788189011578524,0.40234252760516787,0.4064065935405736,0.40234252760516787c0.2235236264473155,0,0.4064065935405736-0.1788189011578524,0.4064065935405736-0.40234252760516787h-0.016256263741622944C0.8859663739184505,0.6502505496649178,0.7112115386960038,0.8250053848873644,0.4998801100549055,0.8250053848873644z,,0.8250053848873644c-0.21133142864109827,0-0.38608626386354494-0.1706907692870409-0.38608626386354494-0.38608626386354494h-0.016256263741622944c0,0.2235236264473155,0.1788189011578524,0.40234252760516787,0.4064065935405736,0.40234252760516787c0.2235236264473155,0,0.4064065935405736-0.1788189011578524,0.4064065935405736-0.40234252760516787h-0.016256263741622944C0.8859663739184505,0.6502505496649178,0.7112115386960038,0.8250053848873644,0.4998801100549055,0.8250053848873644z"/>

        </mask>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

(before:

```
<path d="M123.274,203.551c-52.442,0-95.107-42.662-95.107-95.098h-4.893c0,55.139,44.858,99.991,100,99.991
c55.142,0,100-44.852,100-99.991h-4.893C218.381,160.889,175.713,203.551,123.274,203.551z"/>
```

)

Don't forget to add the 'maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"' Robert Longson mentioned in his comment, else it won't show up. Also, it seems to be important that you give your path a fill in firefox ( fill="#FFFFFF" for example, color doesn't matter ). Chrome doesn't seem to need this.

Comment: do you still have this calculator available?

Answer (score 3):

For people who still want the calculator, it is back on my website:

http://prollygeek.com/svg-mask/

and here is a working example (test on FF)

```css
#test {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  mask: url(#m1);
}
```

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#ffffff;" d="M0.796,0L0.172,0.004C0.068,0.008,0.008,0.068,0,0.172V0.824c0,0.076,0.06,0.16,0.168,0.172h0.652c0.072,0,0.148-0.06,0.172-0.144V0.14C1,0.06,0.908,0,0.796,0zM0.812,0.968H0.36v-0.224h0.312v-0.24H0.36V0.3h0.316l0-0.264l0.116-0c0.088,0,0.164,0.044,0.164,0.096l0,0.696C0.96,0.912,0.876,0.968,0.812,0.968z"
      />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://placebear.com/g/200/200" id="test" alt="">
```

**How Does It work:**
Simply the calclator divides dimensions extracted out of SVG path by the SVG width (or Height, always use highest as your input), and then prints the output.

**Example:**

```
M199.468,0L43.883,1.317C17.289,2.632,2.66,17.106,0,43.423V206.58c0,19.738,15.958,40.789,42.552,43.42
    h163.563c18.619,0,37.235-15.788,43.885-36.84V35.526C250,15.89,227.399,0,199.468,0z M203.456,242.105H90.424v-56.578h78.458
    v-60.526H90.424V75.001h79.787l0.032-66.524l29.961-0.106c22.944,0,41.511,11.853,41.511,24.903l0.304,174.624
    C240.691,228.949,219.415,242.105,203.456,242.105z
```

is equal to (responsive result):

```
M0.796,0L0.172,0.004C0.068,0.008,0.008,0.068,0,0.172V0.824c0,0.076,0.06,0.16,0.168,0.172h0.652c0.072,0,0.148-0.06,0.172-0.144V0.14C1,0.06,0.908,0,0.796,0zM0.812,0.968H0.36v-0.224h0.312v-0.24H0.36V0.3h0.316l0-0.264l0.116-0c0.088,0,0.164,0.044,0.164,0.096l0,0.696C0.96,0.912,0.876,0.968,0.812,0.968z
```